# Java TCP Heartbeat not working properly

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, ioexception

**Project:** I have been working on a wireless mouse app for android that utilizes TCP as the network protocol for transferring mouse movements.

**Objective:**
I decided that implementing a heartbeat TimerTask would be the best way to see if the server has been shutdown. Every 5 seconds that a mouse movement was not made (a mouse movement resets the timer back to 5), a heartbeat of 2 bytes in an array would be sent to the server. Therefore, if the server is shutdown, an `IOException (Broken Pipe)` should raise once a heartbeat is sent.

**My Problem:**
The heartbeat works fine aside from the fact that it loops around 3 times before it throws an exception. Currently, I have it set to 5 seconds before it sends a heartbeat. It will send three heartbeats (15 seconds instead of 5) after the server is closed before it raises the expected exception.

I could potentially set the heartbeat interval to 2 seconds which in turn should take 6 seconds to raise the exception but I would like to know why it's not working the first time.

**Heartbeat code:**

```
 Timer task = new Timer();
                task.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (heartbeat == 1) {
                            byte buf[] = {-96, -96};
                            try {
                                bos.write(buf); // Buffered output stream
                                bos.flush(); // Exception gets thrown here
                                heartbeat = 5;
                                System.out.println("Testing 3");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("Testing 2");
                                launchHomescreen();
                                this.cancel();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Testing 1" + heartbeat);
                            heartbeat--;
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000, 1000);
```

**Log of debug statements:**

```
04-27 00:33:02.339  25410-26259/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Message sending: -99 -99 <-- This is the mouse click that should stop the server
04-27 00:33:03.190  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 15
04-27 00:33:04.201  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 14
04-27 00:33:05.192  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 13
04-27 00:33:06.193  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 12
04-27 00:33:07.203  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 3 <- Should throw the exception here
04-27 00:33:08.194  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 15
04-27 00:33:09.195  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 14
04-27 00:33:10.196  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 13
04-27 00:33:11.187  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 12
04-27 00:33:12.188  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 3
04-27 00:33:13.189  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 15
04-27 00:33:14.190  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 14
04-27 00:33:15.191  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 13
04-27 00:33:16.202  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 12
04-27 00:33:17.193  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse I/System.out﹕ Testing 2 <- but doesn't do it till the third heartbeat
04-27 00:33:17.233  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:508)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:270)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse.MainActivity$connectTask$1.run(MainActivity.java:496)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
04-27 00:33:17.243  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
04-27 00:33:17.253  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:156)
04-27 00:33:17.253  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
04-27 00:33:17.253  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:466)
04-27 00:33:17.253  25410-26264/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/System.err﹕ ... 7 more
04-27 00:33:17.453  25410-25410/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-27 00:33:33.139  25410-25410/com.tutorials.jurko.androidmouse W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Have you looked at a `tcpdump` of the communication between client and server? It looks like the server isn't explicitly closing the socket, and you're seeing a 10 sec timeout from elsewhere in the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'connection reset'/'broken pipe' doesn't happen immediately, because of TCP buffering and asynchronicity. It happens after a write event times out on not receiving an ACK, which can take an appreciable fraction of a minute.

It isn't necessarily related to the number of write attempts, so changing your interval won't necessarily help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to determine the connection status, try doing a `recv` on the socket instead of sending heart beat messages? `recv` would return zero if the server had shutdown and the connection had disappeared. Though this would still fail for cases  where server is unreachable due to n/w issues.

Application keep-alive would work best if both client and server send packet and ack them to each other. Depending on broken pipe will not meet the requirement fully.

Another option is to enable `keep-alive` on the TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for responses, the way I went about solving my problem was by adding a timeout to the socket before the write and then adding a read afterwards. If the read returns -1, then I know that the server stopped. This solution also seems to work just the way I want it to.

**New code:**

```
        Timer task = new Timer();
        task.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (heartbeat == 0) {
                    byte buf[] = {-96, -96};
                    byte send[] = new byte[1024]; // Added this
                    try {
                        socket.setSoTimeout(1000); // Added a timeout every read call
                        bos.write(buf); // Buffered output stream
                        bos.flush();
                        if(socket.getInputStream().read(send) == -1) { // End of stream reached
                            System.out.println("Testing 2");
                            launchHomescreen();
                            this.cancel();
                        }
                        heartbeat = 2;
                        System.out.println("Testing 3");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Testing 2");
                        launchHomescreen();
                        this.cancel();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Testing 1" + heartbeat);
                    heartbeat--;
                }
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
```